# google api client not resolving to a type,while integrating google plus in android app

Tags: android, google-plus, google-api-client

[image]

I am done with the downloads of the respective libraries from https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/downloads/list,
even then the issue is not being resolved,libraries i am referring are
[image]

and the sdk manager is:

[image]

google play services already imported

[image]

Comment: Please post the libraries you are referring.

Comment: @Archie.bpgc question updated...

Comment: add updated google play service library

Comment: @ZeeshanKhan see above in image provided,i guess if the library needs to be updated then there must be a tag in front of it saying updates available(clarify me,if i am wrong)

Comment: import these library into existing project plz follow tutorial http://suslovjb.wordpress.com/2013/09/01/how-to-add-google-play-services-sdk-to-your-project-part-1/

Comment: @ZeeshanKhan i had already imported them,see image.. :(